# Array to string conversion error explode

Tags: php, arrays, explode

OK, so im messing around with explode function and for some reason i keep getting the error below. Can someone please explain to me, what is happening, what the problem is, and how i can fix it.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tutorials/main.php on line 7
>   Array

```
 <?

$names = 'asdasd asdasdasd sadasdasd asdasdas dasdasd asdasdas d';

 $kwame = explode(' ', $names);

 echo $kwame;

?>
```

Comment: $kwame is an array.  echo is converting it to a string.  What do you want to actually do with it?

Answer (score 6):

`$kwame` is an array so you can't use `echo` to show its contents. You can use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

```
print_r($kwame);
```

- [**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Sg7AU3)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `echo` with an array. Use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to see the contents of an array.

```
var_dump($kwame);
```

Comment: Even than, if i do explode('',$names); i still get the same error

Comment: I don't believe you. Look at @JohnConde's demo, it works fine.